# mysql if then statement within select

Tags: php, mysql, fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar for reservation. And I want to display **full** on the date with 10 reservations. And I also want to display the users reservation on corresponding date so that he will know if he already have a reservation for that date. The `event.title` would either be **full** or **my reservation**. If it has 10 reservations, the `event.title` is **full**. If the user have a reservation for that date, the `event.title` is **my reservation**, The `eventSource` is from JSON encoded data from the database. The code below actually work on displaying **full** however it doesn't include **my reservation** yet.

```
SELECT CONCAT('FULL' ) as title, counter, datee as start
   FROM (
       SELECT DATE_FORMAT( dateR,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS datee, 
          COUNT( ID ) AS counter
          FROM reservations
         GROUP BY datee
        )q
WHERE counter=10
```

I tried using `case` but it appears  `#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row`.

```
SELECT
  (case 
    when (select counter
           FROM (
              SELECT DATE_FORMAT( dateR,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS datee,
                COUNT( ID ) AS counter
              FROM reservations
              GROUP BY datee
                 ) q) = 10
            then "full"
     end ) 
   as title;
```

Zoomin:

```
(
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT( dateR,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS datee,
  COUNT( ID ) AS counter
  FROM reservations
  GROUP BY datee
) q
```

Comment: Showing us some sample data from the `reservations` table would go a long way here.

Comment: Tim it is derived table q

Comment: Derived table `q` returns more than 1 row. It becomes counter on the outer wrapper. You are comparing multiple rows to like a 3

Comment: It is like when you do a `select id into myVar from tblXYZ where 1=1` . It explodes

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ymd, if (counter > 9, 'FULL', 'MY RESERVATION') AS Title
FROM (
    SELECT date(dateR) AS ymd, count(*) AS counter
    FROM reservations
    GROUP BY 1
) AS t
```

OR Even Better:

```
SELECT date(dateR) AS ymd, if (count(*) > 9, 'FULL', 'MY RESERVATION') AS Title
FROM reservations
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To simulate an `if` statement, you can use `case`.  Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN counter = 10 THEN 'FULL' ELSE 'MY RESERVATION' END as title, 
   counter, datee as start
FROM (
     SELECT DATE_FORMAT( dateR,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS datee, COUNT( ID ) AS counter
     FROM reservations
     GROUP BY datee
    ) q
```